# Save a layer's renderer to 'undo' the changes in style

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

I'm trying to change a vector layer's style by changing the renderer (from `QgsRuleBasedRenderer` to `QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer`), render an image, and undo the change afterwards:

```
layer = self.get_layer('branch')
old_renderer = layer.renderer()
unique_values = layer.uniqueValues(layer.fields().indexFromName('line_id'))
colors = ['#fa4b3c', '#d900ff', '#a72605', '#879695', '#1fbc00', '#000dff', '#ea75ff', '#fffb00', '#3a7e31', '#ffa560', '#49b9ff', '#00ffb3', ]
categories = []
for unique_value, color in zip(unique_values, colors):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor(color))
    symbol.setWidth(1.25)
    category = QgsRendererCategory(unique_value, symbol, str(unique_value))
    categories.append(category)
layer.setRenderer(QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('line_id', categories))
layer.triggerRepaint()

def finished(path=path):
    img = render.renderedImage()
    img.save("/Users/myuser/render.png", "png")

render.finished.connect(finished)
render.start()
loop = QEventLoop()
render.finished.connect(loop.quit)
loop.exec_()

if old_renderer is not None:
    # layer.setRenderer(old_renderer)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

The above works, but does not undo the change in renderer at the end. If I uncomment the

```
    layer.setRenderer(old_renderer)
```

it crashes the whole app instantaneously.

How do I reapply the old renderer?

Comment: Does it work if you use `old_renderer = layer.renderer().clone()`? FYI if you launch QGIS in a terminal, you might get some information upon crashing.

Comment: `old_renderer = layer.renderer().clone()` should work, same reason as https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/452791/144074

Comment: Great, it works with `clone()`, thanks! Answer it so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some objects accessible in the QGIS Python API are tricky to handle as their actual lifespan might differ from what you'd expect as a Python user.

In Python, objects usually exist until there is no name or other reference "pointing" to them anymore. So you would expect to be able to always access whatever `old_renderer` is a name to and not have your program crash.

In the world of C++ objects made available via the QGIS Python API however, this is not always the case. Objects referenced by whatever magic happens in the background between Python and C++ in memory might get deleted when you don't expect it.

In your case, the renderer object which you assigned a name to with `old_renderer = layer.renderer()` does not exist anymore (probably because the call to `layer.setRenderer()` took care of "cleaning up" the previous renderer but I am not sure) and your program crashes with `wrapped C/C++ object of type (...) has been deleted (...)`.

To avoid this kind of issue, you can create a full blown, independent copy of the object in question using `.clone()`, in this case: `old_renderer = layer.renderer().clone()`

PS: My explanation might not be fully correct but should be alright for a basic understanding of the issue.